# GPO for telemetry set to "Security", regedit still showing AllowTelemetry "3". Is it still effectively "0"?

Tags: registry, windows-10, gpo

I have a GPO that sets "Diagnostics and usage data" to "Security". (see picture)

[image]

From what I understand this should set "AllowTelemetry" value in **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\DataCollection`** to "0". When I check regedit this value is still "3".

[image]

I am pretty sure telemetry is disabled as it's listed as "stopped" when run `get-service diagtrack` in powershell, so basically the question I am asking is:

**If a GPO is in place which sets "Diagnostic and usage data" to security level, does this mean AllowTelemetry is "0" even though the regedit key shows "3"?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I went to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\DataCollection
```

Where AllowTelemetry is '3'

instead of the correct path which is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection
```

Where AllowTelemetry is '0'

Problem solved.